# How to load Image Files into Jetpack Compose Image using Coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I want to *load a local image file* using `Coil` into a Jetpack Compose  `Image`, but searching has produced only methods using web urls or by passing files converted to `bitmap`s.

Can `Coil` *load a local image file directly* into a Compose `Image`?

Comment: Where are stored these files?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti on cache folder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the new version of coil 2.2.2, `rememberImagePainter` didn't give me good results so I used this-

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(<file_path>)
        .build(),
    contentDescription = "icon",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
    modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
)
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Coil` to load any object as a data:

```
val cacheFile = File(context.cacheDir, "filename")
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(cacheFile),
    contentDescription = "...",
)
```

Comment: shouldn't you save the `cacheFile` via `remember`?

Comment: Currently it is deprecated in coil.

Answer (score 4):

If you've a locally saved image path, you can try the following method,

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter(data = File(filePath))
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null)
```

and to load image from remote url,

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter(data = imageUrl)
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null)
```